# SEGV Error Transmission-daemon CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, transmission

Something strange happend with Transmission. It had worked perfect all day, but after I added it to autoboot (via systemctl), it broke.
There is no difference which hdd use to downloading. After few seconds from start daemon stops with this error.

*systemctl status transmission-daemon* :

```
transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2016-11-06 01:44:02 +07; 14s ago
  Process: 2383 ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
 Main PID: 2383 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
   Status: "Uploading 226.05 KBps, Downloading 3503.70 KBps."

Nov 06 01:43:38 kapibara.local systemd[1]: Starting Transmission BitTorrent Daemon...
Nov 06 01:43:38 kapibara.local systemd[1]: Started Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
Nov 06 01:44:02 kapibara.local systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Nov 06 01:44:02 kapibara.local systemd[1]: Unit transmission-daemon.service entered failed state.
Nov 06 01:44:02 kapibara.local systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service failed.
```

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511

Comment: Did you check the logs of said demon/transmission to get more information? Your current output would suggest it was killed because of a memory violation.